# Qgis server error while getprint attlas template containing layer from sql server?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I instaled qgis servere 3.22.5 on windows with xampp apache every thing is ok when i request atlas that have a shapefile layer it done correclty but if the layer is linked from sql server i got error message

Atlas error: empty atlas.

but when i test to connect to the layer by get map i got the layer correclty

my request like that
http://10.1.1.21/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetPrint&MAP=C:/Maps/Projects/samf/samf.qgz&TEMPLATE=p5&CRS=EPSG:4326&ATLAS_PK=1